# Copy stack snippet from jsfiddle

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, jsfiddle

If the original poster creates their snippet on jsfiddle, I'll usually tweak it there until I get it working. But when I want to post an answer, I usually prefer to use a Stack Snippet. So I have to copy each section of the fiddle into the corresponding section of a stack snippet.

It would be nice if there were a command that asked for the URL of a jsfiddle (or codepen, etc.) and it could automatically convert it to a stack snippet.

I also use jsfiddle when I want to write an example to mention in a comment (e.g. when I want to demonstrate that their code actually works). It's not currently possible to use stack snippets outside of questions/answers, is it? If I later need to turn that fiddle into an answer, I'd like to be able to copy from it.

Comment: It would be simpler to ban JSFiddles and **require** Snippets....problem solved. Let's add Codepen / JSBin / Plunker / Bootply  and all the others while we're at it. :)

Comment: @Paulie_D jsfiddle still has its place, because we need it when we're not posting answers. I've updated my question to explain this use case.